# SSRS: show comma instead of dot

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to have in my report a comma instead of a dot.
I used this format:

```
=Format(Fields!True.Value,"F2")
```

But this shows me a dot. How can I get a comma?

Comment: Could you explain if you want comma for thousands or as decimal seperator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to niktrs answer Language settings for the report can be set via the properties window.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, just manually set your `format` string.

For Example:

`=format(10000000.12,"£#,#.##")` will return `£10,000,000.12`

You can use the masks in the same way you would in Excel:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: If I am not wrong, any formating depends on reports selected language. For example if I set report to Greek (dot for thousands and comma for decimals) is there any formating I can do to display a number with comma for thousands and dot for decimals without setting to another language like English?

Answer (score 0):

Number formating depends on reports selected language, so you should set it to something that matches your requirements