# Change seperator in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have case in SSRS where I want change currency format from 3,500,00.00 to 3.500.000,00.

Please help me to change this format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS: show comma instead of dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41872692/ssrs-show-comma-instead-of-dot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In report properties select Language and then select: el-GR.

Select the text box and select text box properties,select number, select currency, check against thousand separator and amend symbol as required.